# custom url for custom module in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, url, module

I am new to Drupal development. So..I have created a new module and named it as 'apps'.

The module simple queries a node from my database and display it. To access this module, I access http://domain/apps/1 where 1 is a node id.

My question is,

how do I change 'apps' to something else without changing the module name?

Answer (score 3):

A path like that is defined in hook_menu(), in your case that should be in the function apps_menu(). You can simply use another path, although it is recommended to stay inside the namespace of your module to avoid conflicts with other modules (see comments for more information).

Comment: «You can change it to whatever you want, there is no connection between the path and the module name.» Technically true, but bad practice. Drupal has no namespacing and using random urls (that do not exactly match your modulename) will at some point cause ugly collisions. Better is to use `/modulename` and then use pathauto to change it to what you wish in the end.

Comment: Sure, but aliases and pathauto can't solve every problem. For example, we recently added a feature to override the default prefix (/messages) to something else, because some sites want to have private messages as a local task in the user profile. There is no way to get to that point by using aliases.

Comment: In that case you should probably have used [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6). Seriously, we recently had to bugfix and rewrite almost 2 months of work, because some remote developer thought it was a good idea to use '/service' and '/services' all over the place, and we needed to implement that in a site that used, indeed, the services module.

Comment: There is no point in using hook_menu_alter() when it is handled directly in hook_menu(). I was not talking about a specific custom site, this is part of a contrib module (Privatemsg). Also the menu definition is the easy part if it, all links and other things need to be dynamic too (eg, for the user/%user/messages prefix, it needs to insert the uid of the current user (or the one of the profile you're accessing) in the link and so on...

Comment: Let me refrase: **existing menu items** (e.g. items provided by other modules) should be modified with `hook_menu_alter()`. **Menu-items in a (custom) module** should start with `/modulename`; in case you don't want your modulename to show up, use path-aliases to then change them into a more human-friendly path.

Answer (score 1):

Use "path" module, it's included in drupal distr., then create manually association "apps" to something other alias. [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) also will useful if you want automate paths aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can also use a [**wildcard loader argument**](http://drupal.org/node/224170).
If you put *%node* in the path, it will automatically call **node_load()** and the page callback **apps_view_node()** receive a fully loaded node object.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu.
*/
function apps_menu() {
  $items = array();
  // With this menu callback, apps_view_node() will receive a node object, instead of an integer.
  $items['apps/%node/view'] = array(
    'type'           => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback'  => 'apps_view_node_obj',
    // 1 is the node object, 2 is 'view'.
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    // Tells the load callback function, node_load(), what part of the URL to load, in this case the literal number 1.
    'load arguments' => array(1),
  );

  // With this menu callback, apps_view_node() will receive an integer.
  $items['apps/%/edit'] = array(
    'type'           => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback'  => 'apps_view_node_int',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
* Custom node view function.
* @param StdClass $node
*   Fully loaded Drupal node object.
*/ 
function apps_view_node_obj($node) {   
  // Do something with the $node object.
  $node->title = "Foo";
  $node->body = "Bar";
  node_save($node);
}

/**
* Custom node view function.
* @param int $id
*   Node id.
*/ 
function apps_view_node_int($id) {   
  // Because we are receiving an id, we must manually load the node object.
  $node = node_load($id);
  $node->title = "Hello";
  $node->body = "World";
  node_save($node);
}
```

Link to [hook_menu documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6).